# how to append dataframes to different excel sheets in for loop

Tags: python, excel, save, openpyxl, xlrd

I have a problem that looks easy to solve at first, but now I'm confused because I still can't solve it.

I have this code that returns few different dataframes within for loop, I need to append different dfs on different excel sheets.

To make it clear:

- inside for loop I get df_a, df_b etc. I need to create file at first iteration of loop and write data to different excel sheets. df_a to sheet_a, df_b to sheet_b etc.
- at second iteration I need to open that file in append mode and append second df_a to sheet_a, second df_b to sheet_b.

**Note**: I don't want to use something like with open each time I need to save dataframe because there is a lot of them if it can be done otherwise.

What I already did:

Using openpyexcel:

```
#with pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer_test:
    for i in range(3):
        with pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer_test:
            a.to_excel(writer_test, sheet_name="name")
            b.to_excel(writer_test, sheet_name="b")
            writer_test.save()
```

Both ways it returns an Excel file with sheets name, b, name1, b1, name2, b2 with data separated.

Without specifying an engine:

```
#with pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", mode="A") as writer_test:
```

for i in range(3):
with pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", mode="A") as writer_test:
a.to_excel(writer_test, sheet_name="name")
b.to_excel(writer_test, sheet_name="b")
writer_test.save()

That just overwrites the data and returns only last iteration.

Another attempt with `openpyexcel`:

```
wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx', read_only=False)

for i in range(3):
    ws = ["mysheet1", "mysheet2"]
    for ws_name in ws:
        if ws_name in wb.get_sheet_names():
            ws_mysheet1 = wb["mysheet1"]
        else:
            ws_mysheet1 = wb.create_sheet() # insert at first position
            ws_mysheet1.title = ws_name
    ws_mysheet1 = wb["mysheet1"]
    ws_mysheet2 = wb["mysheet2"]
    ws_mysheet1.append(a)
    ws_mysheet2.append(b)
```

That does not allow me to save dataframe and returns an error

> TypeError: Value must be a list, tuple, range or generator, or a dict. Supplied value is <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

And I also tried this:

```
for i in range(3):  
    #with open(writer_test, 'a') as f:
        #a.to_excel(writer_test, 'a')
        #b.to_excel(writer_test, 'b')
    if os.path.exists('test.xlsx'):
        append_write = 'a' # append if already exists
    else:
        append_write = 'w' # make a new file if not

    highscore = open('test.xlsx',append_write)
    highscore.write(a + '\n', 'a')
    highscore.write(a + '\n', 'b')
    highscore.close()
```

That results in another error:

> TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

I tried a few other things but they don't work either. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.util.testing.makeDataFrame()
df = df.head()

file = 'output.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'test'

for i in range(3):
    if i == 0:
        df.to_excel(file, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
    else:
        read_data = pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name=sheet_name)
        merge_data = pd.concat([df, read_data])
        merge_data.to_excel(file, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
```

Comment: Yes, i think that would work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: in pandas.ExcelWriter 
mode{‘w’, ‘a’}, default ‘w’ 
File mode to use (write or append). Append does not work with fsspec URLs.